# communication between Java server and Android client using Network Service Discovery

Tags: java, android, client-server, jmdns, dns-sd

I'm building a Java server application (running on a pc) that register itself to the local network using [JmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/), and an Android client App that should discover the java server using [Network Service Discovery](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html).
When I run the android app first, and then run the java server, the app succeed to discover the registerd java server.
**But** when I first run the server and then the android app, the `onDiscoveryStarted` method called but the `onServiceFound` method never triggered - the android app doesn't discover the server. 
This seems to me as an unexpected behavior.

**Succeed case**:
Android app log:
08-24 22:42:06.157  NSD_DISCOVER onCreate
08-24 22:42:06.373  NSD_DISCOVER﹕ onDiscoveryStarted Service discovery started
08-24 22:42:30.256  NSD_DISCOVER﹕ onServiceFound Known Service Type: _http._tcp.
08-24 22:42:30.293  NSD_DISCOVER﹕ onServiceResolved Resolve Succeeded. name: NsdApp, type: ._http._tcp, host: /10.0.0.2, port: 52288

Java server log:
START
REGISTERED
END
WAITING_FOR_MESSAGE
hello world
END_THREAD

**Failure case**:

Android app log:
08-24 22:05:21.690    NSD_DISCOVER﹕ onCreate
08-24 22:05:21.908    NSD_DISCOVER﹕ onDiscoveryStarted Service discovery started

Java server log:
START
REGISTERED
END
WAITING_FOR_MESSAGE

**Server code**

```
public class Server {

    public static String mServiceName = "NsdApp";
    public static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp.local";

    static ServerSocket mServerSocket;


    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        System.out.println("START");

    try {
        mServerSocket = new ServerSocket(0);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("ServerSocket(0) FAILED");
    }

    int mPort = mServerSocket.getLocalPort();

    JmDNS jmdns = JmDNS.create();
    ServiceInfo info = ServiceInfo.create(SERVICE_TYPE, mServiceName, mPort, "B");
    jmdns.registerService(info);

    System.out.println("REGISTERED");

    jmdns.close();

    Thread mReceiveMessage = new Thread(new ReceiveMessage());
    mReceiveMessage.start();

    System.out.println("END");
}

public static class ReceiveMessage implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        System.out.println("WAITING_FOR_MESSAGE");
        try {

            Socket clientSocket = mServerSocket.accept(); 
            InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader); 
            String message = bufferedReader.readLine();
            System.out.println(message);

            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStreamReader.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            System.out.println("END_THREAD");

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.out.println("Problem in message reading");
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Client code**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static final String TAG = "NSD_DISCOVER";
public static final String SERVICE_TYPE = "_http._tcp.";
NsdManager.DiscoveryListener mDiscoveryListener;
NsdManager.ResolveListener mResolveListener;
NsdManager mNsdManager;
int port;
InetAddress host;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.v(TAG, "onCreate");

    mNsdManager = (NsdManager) getSystemService(Context.NSD_SERVICE);
    initializeResolveListener();
    initializeDiscoveryListener();
    mNsdManager.discoverServices(SERVICE_TYPE, NsdManager.PROTOCOL_DNS_SD, mDiscoveryListener);
}


public void initializeDiscoveryListener() {
    mDiscoveryListener = new NsdManager.DiscoveryListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStarted(String regType) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onDiscoveryStarted Service discovery started");
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceFound(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            if (!service.getServiceType().equals(SERVICE_TYPE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "onServiceFound Unknown Service Type: " + service.getServiceType());
            } else {
                Log.v(TAG, "onServiceFound Known Service Type: " + service.getServiceType());
                mNsdManager.resolveService(service, mResolveListener);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceLost(NsdServiceInfo service) {
            Log.e(TAG, "service lost" + service);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDiscoveryStopped(String serviceType) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Discovery stopped: " + serviceType);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStopDiscoveryFailed(String serviceType, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Discovery failed: Error code:" + errorCode);
            mNsdManager.stopServiceDiscovery(this);
        }
    };
}


public void initializeResolveListener() {
    mResolveListener = new NsdManager.ResolveListener() {

        @Override
        public void onResolveFailed(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo, int errorCode) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onResolveFailed Resolve failed" + errorCode);
        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceResolved(NsdServiceInfo serviceInfo) {
            Log.v(TAG, "onServiceResolved Resolve Succeeded. " + serviceInfo);
            port = serviceInfo.getPort();
            host = serviceInfo.getHost();

            SendMessage sendMessageTask = new SendMessage();
            sendMessageTask.execute();
        }
    };
}


private class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {

            Socket client;
            PrintWriter printwriter;

            client = new Socket(host, port); 
            printwriter = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream(), true);
            printwriter.write("hello world"); 

            printwriter.flush();
            printwriter.close();
            client.close(); 

        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling `jmdns.close()` right after registering.  Your service is only discoverable as long as you have jmdns open.  You should remove that call to `close`, make your `jmdns` variable a member of your class, and then only call close on it when you don't want your services to be discoverable anymore.  Also, it is good form to call `unregisterAllServices()` before closing jmdns.